# Enable tabs one after the other on form submission

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

There are 4 tabs and in that 4 tabs there are 4 forms, I want to write a jQuery program such that if I submit `Form1` in `tab1` then the `tab2` containing form should be enabled and when I submit `form2`, `tab3` containing form 3 should be enabled that goes on until I reach `form4`.

I wrote the code but it is enabling all tabs instead of next one.

I am a beginner in jQuery, please comment below for any query.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Case</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

</head>
<body>

<div class="container">

  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myLinks">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Tab1</a></li>
    <li><a  href="#menu1">Tab2</a></li>
    <li><a  href="#menu2">Tab3</a></li>
    <li><a  href="#menu3">Tab4</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="tab-content" id="myTabs">
    <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
        <h1>Form 1</h1>
        <form>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Email:</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Enter password">
      </div>
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label><input type="checkbox"> Remember me</label>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
  </form>
    </div>
    <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">
        <h1>Form 2</h1>
        <form>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Email:</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Enter password">
      </div>
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label><input type="checkbox"> Remember me</label>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
  </form>
    </div>
    <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade">
        <h1>Form 3</h1>
        <form>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Email:</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Enter password">
      </div>
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label><input type="checkbox"> Remember me</label>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
  </form>
    </div>
    <div id="menu3" class="tab-pane fade">
        <h1>Form 4</h1>
        <form>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Email:</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Enter password">
      </div>
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label><input type="checkbox"> Remember me</label>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
  </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
 $("#myTabs form").on('submit',function() {
   $('#myLinks li a').each(function(){
    $(this).attr('data-toggle','tab');
   });
 });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/27636/)**.

You could check on submit if the current active tab is the last or not, if not move to the next tab using the `.next()` and `.tab('show')`:

```
$('.nav-tabs li.active').next('li').find('a').attr('data-toggle','tab').tab('show');
```

I think that what you looking for :

```
$("#myTabs form").on('submit',function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var li_count = $('.nav-tabs li').length;
  var current_active = $('.nav-tabs li.active').index();

  if(current_active<li_count){
    $('.nav-tabs li.active').next('li').find('a').attr('data-toggle','tab').tab('show');
  }else{
    alert('Last Step');
  }
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Is that what you're looking for @R K?

Comment: But after enabling the 2nd, 3rd and 4th tab if I click on to the !st tab again it re-disables the 3 tabs.

Comment: What you mean by re-disables?

Comment: I mean I can't access the 2nd 3rd and 4th tab once i click on first tab after i access the 2nd, 3rd or 4rth tab on form submission in your fiddle, which my teacher considers a defect.

Comment: Ah my bad.. i see, i was just missing `.attr('data-toggle','tab')`, updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution: [Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ionutmihai1995/vo1npqdx/54/)

When you submit the form,you need to `show` next tab. For that, you should to identify current `li` ,then, set `data-toggle="tab"` for next `li`.

```
$("#myTabs form").on('submit',function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var linkHref=$(this).parents('.tab-pane').attr('id');
    $('#myLinks li')
        .find('a[href="#'+linkHref+'"]')
        .parent()
        .next()
        .find('a').tab('show')
        .attr('data-toggle','tab');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Case</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

</head>
<body>

<div class="container">

  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myLinks">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Tab1</a></li>
    <li><a  href="#menu1">Tab2</a></li>
    <li><a  href="#menu2">Tab3</a></li>
    <li><a  href="#menu3">Tab4</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="tab-content" id="myTabs">
    <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
        <h1>Form 1</h1>
        <form>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Email:</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Enter password">
      </div>
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label><input type="checkbox"> Remember me</label>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
  </form>
    </div>
    <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">
        <h1>Form 2</h1>
        <form>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Email:</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Enter password">
      </div>
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label><input type="checkbox"> Remember me</label>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
  </form>
    </div>
    <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade">
        <h1>Form 3</h1>
        <form>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Email:</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Enter password">
      </div>
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label><input type="checkbox"> Remember me</label>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
  </form>
    </div>
    <div id="menu3" class="tab-pane fade">
        <h1>Form 4</h1>
        <form>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Email:</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Enter password">
      </div>
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label><input type="checkbox"> Remember me</label>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
  </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
 $("#myTabs form").on('submit',function() {
   $('#myLinks li a').each(function(){
    $(this).attr('data-toggle','tab');
   });
 });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```